# Apply on click javascript event to a header in JSP instead of using <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, href

I currently have a header with a toggle button which will expand on click.

Html :

```
<h3 class="toggle_header" id="Tax_information_eSignature">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon_toggle_open"></a>
    <spring:message code="TaxInformation.eSignature" />
    <label for="Tax_information_eSignature"></label>
</h3>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.icon_toggle_open', function (e) {
        stop(e);
        $(this).removeClass("icon_toggle_open")
            .addClass("icon_toggle_close")
            .attr("alt","Show")
            .attr("title","Show")
            .parent().next('.toggle_content').hide();
        $(window).blur();       
      });

     $(document).on('click', '.icon_toggle_close', function (e) {
        stop(e);
        $(this).removeClass("icon_toggle_close")
            .addClass("icon_toggle_open")
            .attr("alt","Hide")
            .attr("title","Hide")
            .parent().next('.toggle_content').show();
        $(window).blur();       
      });
```

It is currently working as expected. The user needs to click on the toggle icon to expand the div. [image]

Instead of clicking on the expand button, I want the Expand/collapse to be triggered upon clicking anywhere in the accordion bar. I am new to JSP, can anyone help?

Comment: remove id or class on which the toggle is performing and add it to the anchor tag which is showing in your question or it will better to help you if you share full code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set the event listener higher in the DOM. Try moving your event listener from `.icon_toggle_open` to `.toggle_header`.

```
$(document).on('click', '.toggle_header', function (e) {
  stop(e);
  var opened = $(this).children('.icon_toggle_open')
  if(opened.length > 0){
    opened
      .removeClass("icon_toggle_open")
      .addClass("icon_toggle_close")
      .attr("alt","Show")
      .attr("title","Show")
      .parent().next('.toggle_content').hide();
  } else {
    $(this)
      .children(".icon_toggle_close")
      .removeClass("icon_toggle_close")
      .addClass("icon_toggle_open")
      .attr("alt","Hide")
      .attr("title","Hide")
      .parent().next('.toggle_content').show();
  }
  $(window).blur(); 
});
```

Comment: Didn't work, Ill share a screenshot of what happened along with a part of the console that might help.
https://pasteboard.co/dcOv9x8Rz.png

Comment: Almost there. Expand is working, but not collapsing. Thank you

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Apply and event listener to the entire `h3` instead of the `a` tag:

```
document.querySelector('#Tax_information_eSignature').addEventListener('click', e => {
    // Expand your accordion bar by selecting it
});
```

I don't know how you have set up the 'expansion' feature but I would like to see how you've done your javascript to expand the accordion bar.